# FFmpeg: How do I split a 100GB MP4 file into several 1GB files?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I've tried using the -fs switch, but it only creates a single file. The -f segment option allows me to use the -segment_time option, but that only limits the video duration, not its size.

So, suppose I want to use ffmpeg to split a 100GB MP4 file into several 1GB MP4 files, what's the switch?

Comment: check http://docs.unified-streaming.com/documentation/package/package.html  'mp4split'

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in `ffmpeg` is... to not use `ffmpeg` ;)

What I would suggest instead is to use [MP4Box](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/):

```
MP4Box -splits 1048576 path/to/file
```

(The argument `-splits` needs the file size in kilobytes; 1GB in kilobytes is `1048576`.)

Comment: It looks like MP4Box is part of GPAC - and that requires a non-trivial amount of compiling and installing of software by the user first. It looks fantastic for sure, but is there a python-based way to do this also?

Comment: @uhoh Depending on the distro, you might find a package. Anyway have a look here: http://icephoenix.us/notes-for-myself/auto-splitting-video-file-in-equal-chunks-with-ffmpeg-and-python/   It won't split by size, but by time.

Comment: Thank you! - that link is very helpful and well commented.